# Dataset in Foundry has a marking that appeared from nowhere

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

I have a dataset in Foundry that has a marking, but none of its input datasets have a marking. How did the marking appear on my dataset?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. The dataset is out of date and the last time it was built the input datasets had a marking applied to them. (Or a marking was retroactively applied to old versions of the input datasets)
2. If the dataset is up to date, the marking was directly applied to the dataset or its parent folder/project.